# Unable to execute sfdx force:lightning:test:run -a jasmineTests.app in my scratch org from CLI on windows system

Tags: lightning-aura-components, unit-test, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, jasmine

I am unable to execute this command `sfdx force:lightning:test:install` in my scratch org from CLI. It gives a warning.

`sfdx force:lightning:test:install`

Result:

`Warning: force:lightning:test:install is not a sfdx command.`

I have tried installing LTS using the answer provided in this link,  [Cannot install Lightning testing service in scratch orgs anymore](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/267222/cannot-install-lightning-testing-service-in-scratch-orgs-anymore), it installs however I am not able to execute the command

`sfdx force:lightning:test:run -a jasmineTests.app`

Result:

`Warning: force:lightning:test:run is not a sfdx command.`

Can anyone let me know why I am getting the warnings? And how to resolve this so that I can execute the commands. I am new to Salesforce.

[image]

Comment: I believe you need to install the plugin on sfdx: `sfdx plugins:install plugin-lightning-testing-service` see the [repository](https://github.com/forcedotcom/LightningTestingService).

Comment: The installation also seems to be a different command: `sfdx aura-test:install`. Plus the test seems to have changed to `sfdx aura-test:run`.

Comment: The overall point is: if you are trying to test Aura, that seems to be deprecated but it seems to be the tool, but if you are testing LWC look into these [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/testing).